# id3lib extract tags

Tags: c++, mp3, id3lib

I try to use ID3lib from C++. 
I tested near 50 mp3  files and most often I get answer that files haven't any tags.
But actually, they are there ( I check it using another software and it shows them properly)

Actually, I've done nothing, I'd only linked library and copied example from [offficial documentation](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/id3lib-manual.php)

```
 void next_try()
 {
  ID3_Tag tag;
  tag.Link("file.mp3");
  cout<<"success\n";
  cout<<tag.GetFileSize()<<"\n";

   ID3_Frame *frame;
    if ( frame = tag.Find ( ID3FID_TITLE ) )
      {
       char title[ 1024 ];
       frame->Field ( ID3FN_TEXT ).Get ( title, 1024 );
       cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
      }
    else
     cout<<"not found\n";
 }
```

And a file that does have tags http://zalil.ru/33733757

But I get answer that it hasn't tag. But it has!!!
And it's not a single occurrence. I wonder whether this library really works.

Perhaps someone had experience with this library. 
Moreover I am confused, because there are links on the [official page](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) to the working projects, so it has been proven that library can work properly. 
Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id3lib is no longer maintained and quite outdated as it does have no support for ID3v2.4.

You can easily see that with `hexdump -C -n4 your.mp3`:

`00000000  49 44 33 03   |ID3.|
00000004`

If the mp3 file starts with ID3 and the 4th byte is a 03, it will work with id3lib. If there's a 04 it's using ID3v2.4.

Comment: thanks, still nice to know why after more than for years

Comment: I had the problem today and found your question trying to understand, so it could be still relevant for others as well :-). There are still several programs around that rely on id3lib instead of the well maintained taglib.